# Swift: remove all whitespace characters from a string

Tags: swift, whitespace

I'd like to use `CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines` to remove whitespace from a string.

However, the code below does not compile.

```
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines, with: "")
// Instance method 'replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)' requires that 'CharacterSet' conform to 'StringProtocol'
```

What is a simple way to achieve the intended result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
let result = myString.filter { !$0.isWhitespace }
```